# Getting an error name "index out of range" while playing around list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, index-error

I am a beginner and I am playing around a list where I have seen this error and got stuck. How can I fix it? What is the reason? Is there a solution?

```
row1 = ["", "", ""]
row2 = ["", "", ""]
row3 = ["", "", ""]
map = [row1 + row2 + row3]
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}\n")
position = input("Where do you want to put the treasures?")
row = int(position[0])
column = int(position[1])
map[row-1][column-1] = "x"
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}\n")
```

**Output**

```
 ['', '', '']
 ['', '', '']
 ['', '', '']

Where do you want to put the tresures?23
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
map[row-1][column-1]="x"
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `map`? It looks like this: `[['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]`. It's a 1-element list, so index 2 is out of range.

Comment: @DallogFheir Should've been an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in these lines:

```
map=[row1+row2+row3]
# and later:
map[row-1][column-1]="x"
```

When you are passing `23` as an input, the second line from above becomes:

```
map[1][2]="x"
```

`map` (as @DallogFheir pointed out) is a 2D array (list) with 1 row only

```
map = [['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

This is because of the intialization of `map` as `[row1+row2+row3]`. So trying to access 2nd row is giving you that error.

Solution: Change the first intialization to following:

```
map=[row1,row2,row3]
```

Comment: yes it is working right now, thanks alot for the quick Help <3

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that a valid index into a non-empty list of length N will be in the range:

```
-N -> N-1
```

It looks like you want 3 rows each of 3 columns. If that's the case your concatenation of row1, row2 and row3 is incorrect.

It's **very important** to validate user input. Failure to do so is likely to lead to runtime errors.

Don't use names of Python built-in functions as variable names (in this case *map*).

Here's what I suggest:

```
row1 = ["", "", ""]
row2 = ["", "", ""]
row3 = ["", "", ""]

Map = [row1, row2, row3]

print(*Map, sep='\n')

# User input values are base 1
# Empty input terminates the loop
while (position := input('Where do you want to put the treasure? ')):
    try:
        if len(position) != 2:
            raise ValueError('Format is RC')
        row, col = map(int, position)
        if row < 1 or row > len(Map):
            raise ValueError('Row number is out of range')
        if col < 1 or col > len(Map[row-1]):
            raise ValueError('Column number is out of range')
        Map[row-1][col-1] = ''
        print(*Map, sep='\n')
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Invalid input ->', e)
```

**Console:**

```
['', '', '']
['', '', '']
['', '', '']
Where do you want to put the treasure? 11
['', '', '']
['', '', '']
['', '', '']
Where do you want to put the treasure? 22
['', '', '']
['', '', '']
['', '', '']
Where do you want to put the treasure? 33
['', '', '']
['', '', '']
['', '', '']
Where do you want to put the treasure?
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this - I did little modification to your code

```
rows, colums = (3,3)
map = [[""]*colums]*rows
for row in map:
    print(row)
postion=str(input("where to you want to put the tresures"))
row=int(postion[0])
column=int(postion[1])
map[(row-1)][(column-1)] = "x"
for row in map:
    print(row)
```

Comment: thanks alot, in this way it is alot more better, you gave me a new way to do this. thanks alot

Comment: *input()* returns type str. Call to *str()* is redundant. Why all the redundant parentheses? What if the input is inconsistent with the bounds of the lists?

Comment: Do you think , we give entire script to handle all the scenarios in stack overflow. looks like you accept answers with unitests on the stack overflow. We pointed out where he was wrong. He was not using 2d array. Rest he should handle from his end.

Comment: @DayanandaDR your solution does not meet OP's requirement. your `map` variable has been initialized in a very dangerous way, `by copying references` of the same 1D list `row` times. Which means you will have updated all rows when you execute `map[(row-1)][(column-1)] = "x"`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of modifying code and playing with numbers, there is a much better option. The best practice would be to check whether the index is valid and if it is valid, fire the exception or handle it another way.

You can use the below function to check whether its index is within range or now

```
def check_list_index(lst, index):
 if index >= 0 and index < len(lst):
    return True
 else:
    return False
```

Comment: Indentation is wrong. For a non-empty list an index of -1 (for example) would be valid but not according to your logic

Comment: Hi, Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected the error